# Store ols regression results as a dictionary/dataframe or list

Tags: python, linear-regression

Once we do OLS regression is there a way to store the data as a dictionary/list or dataframe?

I got my results for OLS regression and printed them using model.params
and this is what I get:

intercept  -1.5
varX       -0.4
varY        1.4
varZ       -0.21

How can I store this as dataframe so that I can output it as a csv or excel file.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is `model.params` a list, a numpy array? Please, add an example.

Comment: say I have a df with two columns X and Y. 
then this is what my code looks like:
model = smf.ols(formula = X~Y, data = df)
model_fit = model.fit()
then I can get the parameters of the model by using print(model_fit.params) and it prints the coefficients.